# SSAS: "Unexpected Exception Occurred" when trying to use a calculated measure

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx, cube, olap-cube

Running Analysis Services version 2012.

I've written a calculated measure to calculate a weighted version of a "target" value (which are granular by month) depending on how many days have passed in for the selected months (based on having a value for "MyMeasure"), below:

```
(
COUNT(NONEMPTY(DESCENDANTS(NONEMPTY(DESCENDANTS([Date].[Dates].CURRENTMEMBER,[Date].[Dates].[Month]),[Measures].[Target]),[Date].[Dates].[Date]),[Measures].[MyMeasure]))
/
COUNT(DESCENDANTS(NONEMPTY(DESCENDANTS([Date].[Dates].CURRENTMEMBER,[Date].[Dates].[Month]),[Measures].[Target]),[Date].[Dates].[Date]))
) * [Measures].[Target]
```

Or more simply put:

> (Number of days with targets AND that have passed / Number of days
>   with targets) * Sum of Target

If I run either of the two following MDX statements after deploying and full processing the cube the results are as expected:

```
SELECT [Date].[Dates].[Year].&[2016] ON ROWS,
[Measures].[WeightedTarget] ON COLUMNS
FROM [MyCube]

SELECT [Date].[Dates].[Month].&[201601] ON ROWS,
[Measures].[WeightedTarget] ON COLUMNS
FROM [MyCube]
```

...however if I attempt to use the calculated member in conjunction with my date dimension in Excel I receive the error :

> We couldn't get data from the source. Here's the error we got:
>
> Internal error: An unexpected exception occurred.

I get the same message when I try to browse from directly within SSAS.

I'm kind of baffled on this and have no real starting point owing to the vagueness of the error. Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: Can you open SQL Server Profiler and connect to SSAS. Then try to build a PivotTable in Excel using that calculation. Either a better error message will show up in Excel or you will at lease get the MDX query Excel ran. Run that MDX query in SSMS and let us know what SSMS says.

Comment: I'd recommend to create three separate calculations and test them.

Comment: @GregGalloway, thanks for your comment. I've ran profiler and it seems that the following MDX query is being run. When I run this in SSMS I get the same error as before:

`SELECT {[Measures].[Target]} 
DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME ON COLUMNS , 
NON EMPTY Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[Date].[Dates].[All]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)}) 
DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS  
FROM [MyCube] CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, LANGUAGE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FONT_FLAGS`

Comment: @SeeBeeEss sounds like an SSAS bug. I would install the latest cumulative update or service pack and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @GregGalloway, I also did what Danylo Korostil suggested and ran the calculations independently. It would appear that this `COUNT(NONEMPTY(DESCENDANTS(NONEMPTY(DESCENDANTS([Date].[Dates].CURRENTMEMBER,[Date].[Dates].[Month]),[Measures].[ Target]),[Date].[Dates].[Date]),[Measures].[MyMeasure]))` query is the culprit, the other statement in the divide operation, which is identical apart from the first `NONEMPTY` clause, is fine.

Comment: To pseudocode this operation:

> Get all descendants at the month level of the current selected month
> Filter this to only tuples that have a 'Target' measure (this measure is at the month grain)
> Of this list of tuples, then get all of the descendants at the day level
**> Filter this to only the tuples that have a 'MyMeasure' measure** _(this is the part that it doesn't seem to like)_

Comment: Does NonEmpty([Da‌​te].[Dates].[Month].Members, [Measures].[Target]).Count work for you? I'd recommend to rewrite the code step by step to find the smallest piece of the broken code.